# Button Joda Time +1day?

Tags: java, android, date, button, jodatime

My app uses Joda Time to save the data at midnight. (with LocalDate and sharedpref)

But for a school demonstration, I would like to create a button (very simple) to advance the date of ONE day. To show that the data are recorded.

(I have already created the button in my XML file, it stay only Java)

How should I do it?

Thank you :D
(i'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(1);
```

Comment: thanks! But how can i use this in my code button (onClick)? Where to place it?

Comment: Inside your onClick method you can put this directly

Comment: in " DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);" ,  the "(date)" = cannot resolve symbol "date" :(